# Como tornar uma data por extenso em data comum?

Tags: php, data

Recebo uma string com uma data, e infelizmente não há como alterá-la, no formato:

> 1 de setembro de 2015

E torná-la em:

> 01/09/2015

A única maneira que encontrei de fazer isso seria quebrando a string e formando um array, e verificar as partes necessárias. Mas há alguma outra forma?

Sei que não há como utilizando **strtotime** e **strftime**.

Comment: Vai ter que fazer uma função, amigo. Posso pressentir o paleativo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma de resolver isso é substituir as o mês me portugues pelo em inglês atraves de um array com a ajuda de `str_replace()`.

```
<?php

$en = ['','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
$pt = [' de ', 'janeiro', 'fevereiro', 'março', 'abril', 'maio', 'junho', 'julho', 'agosto', 'setembro', 'outubro', 'novembro', 'dezembro']; 

$data = '1 de setembro de 2015';
$data = str_replace($pt, $en, $data);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data));
```

Comment: @JJoao pq `' '` ? no caso do `de` estar colado? isso já n vai converter a data corretamente.

Comment: @JJoao, correto, na hora de convter dezembro ele substituia o `de` por nada, adicionei sua correção. obrigado :D

Answer (score 1):

Eu Faria da seguinte forma:

```
function arruma_data($data){
    $arr_mes = array("Setembro"=>"09","Outubro"=>"10","Novembro"=>"11");
    $arr_data = explode(" de ",data)
    $datafim = str_pad($arr_data [0],2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."/".$arr_mes[$arr_data[1]]."/". $arr_data[2];
    return $datafim;
}

echo $this->arrumada_data("1 de setembro de 2015");
```