# Como converter data no format "September 18, 2018" em PHP?

Tags: php, libcurl

Usei um `cURL`, para fazer uma *api*, no qual pegava uma data especifica.

O problema é que o conteúdo retornado é em inglês, por exemplo: `September 18, 2018`.

Como poderia formatar isso para "pt-br"?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$espdata = GetStr($data,'<exemplo>','</exemplo>');
echo $espdata; //September 18, 2018
```

Comment: [Como tornar uma data por extenso em data comum?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83726/91)

Comment: Olá, jovem. não edite a pergunta dessa forma. Você praticamente tirou as respostas de contexto ao fazer essa edição. Eu reverti. Se tiver outra dúvida, faça outra pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplesmente, use a classe `DateTime`.

```
new DateTime('September 18, 2018')
```

Resultado:

```
DateTime {#168
     +"date": "2018-09-18 00:00:00.000000",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
   }
```

Se gosta de usar a função `date`, você pode combiar com `strtotime`:

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime('September 18, 2018'))
```

Resultado:

```
 "18/09/2018"
```

A o construtor da classe `DateTime` e a função `strtotime` interpreta uma string e transforma em data.

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/n7tHGq)

Answer (score -2):

experimenta

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$data = new DateTime();
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('pt_BR',
                                    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
                                    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,          
                                    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);
echo $formatter->format($data);
```

Comment: -1 De que forma isso responde a pergunta? Cadê o parâmetro da data que o AP quer converter?

Comment: Sugiro clicar na opção "editar" e adicionar informações à sua resposta. Eu considerarei remover meu voto negativo.