# Converter formato de data em php

Tags: php, datetime, data

Pessoal estou trabalhando com Wordpress php e recebo do banco de dados uma data no seguinte formato: "22 Outubro, 2018", mais preciso converter ela para "2018-10-22",
como consigo isso?

tentei:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime(get_post_meta( $id_pedido, "Data de entrega", true )));
```

mais não deu muito certo, o valor retornado é "1970-01-01" e não a data informada.
Obrigado!

Comment: Precisa adaptar um pouco mais em linhas gerais é isso => [Como tornar uma data por extenso em data comum?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83741/91)

Comment: Cara, `Outubro` está em português mesmo?

Comment: Sim, mano.. tentei essas respostas ae mais nenhuma deu certo.

Comment: @wDrik não tem essa data o banco não? Realmente precisa pegar a que vem do WP? Ou o WP salva assim no banco (se for, é mancada do WP)

Comment: Então mano é assim que o wordpress está retornando. =/ 
fazer uma query pra isso acho que vai dar mais trampo! kkkkk

Comment: get_post_meta( $id_pedido, "Data de entrega", true ) está retornando a data corretamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pessoal obrigado a todos consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
$data_de_entrega = get_post_meta( $id_pedido, "Data de entrega", true );
$pt = [',', 'Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro']; 
$en = ['','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
$data_new = str_replace($pt, $en, $data_de_entrega);

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data_new));
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a função `substr()` do PHP.
Ex:

```
$data = "22 Outubro, 2018";

$ano = substr($data,-4); //4 dos últimos 4 caracteres e o "-" para começar a contar do final.

$dia = substr($data,0,2; //0 do ponto inicial e 2 para dois caracteres a partir de 0.

$mes_array = explode(" ", $data);//Separa nos espaços a string "data" e transforma em um array.
$mes = $mes_array[1];//Seleciona o a segunda posição do array.
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode montar algo mais simples que sugerido no link. O primeiro passo é definir dois arrays um de busca e outro de substiuição (de português para inglês) pois os nomes dos meses ou dias da da semana não podem ser convertidos em uma data válida se especificados em português. Note que o primeiro elemento de `$en` é uma vígula que será substituida por nada.

Depois de limpa (feita a substituição com `str_ireplace()`) a string basta chamar o método `createFromFormat()` de `DateTIme` definido o formato de entrada que no caso é o dia (`d`) seguindo do mês por extenso (`F`) e por último o ano com quatro dígitos (`Y`).

`format()` define a formatação deseja `Y-m-d`.

```
$pt = [',', 'janeiro', 'fevereiro', 'março', 'abril', 'maio', 'junho', 'julho', 'agosto', 'setembro', 'outubro', 'novembro', 'dezembro']; 
$en = ['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F Y', str_ireplace($pt, $en,'22 maio, 2018'));
echo $data->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/NmuK4H)

Answer (score -1):

Tenta fazer isso:

```
$tempo = strtotime("22 October 2018");
echo date("Y-m-d", $tempo);
```

Lembrando que a função espera que seja informada uma string contendo um formato de data em inglês US, neste caso, "22 October 2018".

**Nota**: Isso serve também para todos os outros meses, ou seja, você deverá adicionar o mês escrito em inglês.

Para mais informações: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php

Comment: -1 A pergunta está como "outubro" e não "october". Sua resposta não se aplica.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters respeito sua opinião, porém, quem aceitou e avaliou essa resposta como melhor resposta foi o autor da pergunta, sendo assim, útil para ele (bom que o ajudou). Ao meu ver é ele quem tem o dever de me dizer se a minha resposta se aplica ou não, porém, agradeço o seu feedback!

Comment: Errado. Você não está respondendo apenas para o AP, você está respondendo para a comunidade. As pessoas que entrarem aqui deverão se beneficiar das respostas aqui colocadas. Isso deveria ser uma coisa que tanto quem pergunta como quem responde deveria ter consciência.